# How can I use emoji characters in a Velocity Template

Tags: java, velocity

I am trying to use emoji characters in my velocity templates. The templates are being read into a Java string using

```
Template template = getVelocityEngine().getTemplate(templateRef, "UTF-8");

VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext(); 

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
template.merge( context, writer );
result = writer.toString();
```

In the template, I tried to escape the smiley face like: \xF0\x9F\x98\x81

Comment: Did you try just inserting the character?

Comment: It works. Feel a bit embarrassed I was trying to go about it the hard way.

Comment: Unicode support is still wacky enough that it's easy to forget.